# How do I send a user inputted value from my Frontend HTML to my backend server?

Tags: html, node.js, frontend, backend

Currently, I have an input in my frontend html, and I extract that value using client side JS – yet I want to be able to access this value from my backend server? How would I go about sending that value?

I'm not using any frameworks – just pure JS on the frontend, and Node.js and Express on the backend.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? E.g. are you using any kind of Framework in backend ? Do you use jQuery in Frontend JS ? Do you already know how to define a route in the backend ?

Comment: do http request to your backend

Comment: How do you want to use the value ? Do you want to use it as an input for a GET request or a property for a POST / PUT / DELETE request etc ??? And is your input part of a FORM on the front end

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route in backend to handle the data. Add following snippet to your backend implementation:

```
app.post('/handle_data', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var processing_ok = true;
  // Process data from req.body as needed
  if (processing_ok) {
      response.send("The data has been processed");
  } else {
      response.status(500).send("An error occurred while processing the data");
  }
});
```

To pass the data from frontend to backend you can use an AJAX request. In pure JS, this looks like:

```
var data = "The data you want to send to the server";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/handle_data');
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) { // Check if request was succesfully processed
    alert("Error " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText); 
  } else {
    alert("Result = " + xhr.response);
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("An error occured.");
};
```